# process while loop according to the size of the list

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist, while-loop, conditional-statements

I need to call different functions according to the size of the array list.
ie, something like

```
List<String> lsNextPages = new ArrayList<String>(); 
if(lsNextPages.size() == 0){
    lsNextPages = fuction1(parentLink);
}
if(lsNextPages.size() == 0){
    lsNextPages = function2(parentLink);
}
if(lsNextPages.size() == 0){
    lsNextPages = function3(parentLink);
}
```

for avoiding if loop checking after each function call, i tried

```
while(lsNextPages.size() == 0){
            lsNextPages = function1(parentLink);
            lsNextPages = function2(parentLink);
            lsNextPages = function3(parentLink);
        }
```

But this is not working. What is the reason for that and how can i do this?  Thanks.

With your permision, i am adding one more example:

```
public static void main(String []args) {
        List<String> lsNextPages = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        while(lsNextPages.size() == 0){
            lsNextPages = function1();
            lsNextPages = function2();
            lsNextPages = function3();
        }
        System.out.println(lsNextPages);
}

    static public List<String> function1(){
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();;
        return list;
    }
    static public List<String> function2(){
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("1","2");
        return list;
    }
    static public List<String> function3(){
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("1","2","3");
        return list;
    }
```

What i need is if the first function gives a non empty list, do not call the following function. ie,function2 gives a non empty list.so do not call function3. i need a output like [1,2]. 
But here the output is [1,2,3].
The output is same if i change the `while` loop with `if` loop.

Comment: Please give us a different example. Currently you only have one size.

Comment: Why you have 3 `if`s with the same condition?

Comment: Also make sure you decrement the size the size of lsNextPages or else you will end up in a infinite loop.

Comment: Use `Iterator` if you don not know the size of an `ArrayList`.

Comment: I hv modified the question. please check it.

Answer (score 1):

Why did you choose while, this will do functions 1 - 3 over and over. Why not

```
if(lsNextPages.size() == 0){
            lsNextPages = function1(parentLink);
            lsNextPages = function2(parentLink);
            lsNextPages = function3(parentLink);
        }
```

Comment: i modified the question. please check it.

Answer (score 1):

You have replaced your 3 `if(lsNextPages.size() == 0){` conditions with a while loop. The behavior cannot be guaranteed if the size of the list remains `0` then while loop may execute more than once and possibly infinite times as well.
I think you must try this:

```
if(lsNextPages.size() == 0){
  lsNextPages = function1(parentLink);
  lsNextPages = function2(parentLink);
  lsNextPages = function3(parentLink);
}
```

Comment: i modified the question. please check it.